# iOS 8 APIs on iOS 7 devices

Tags: ios8, backwards-compatibility

It seems that new ios 8 APIs such as Local Authentication run on ios 7 without crashing. Of course, the actual policy validation fails (gracefully without a crash), but given that the API is brand new in ios 8, how is it that the app does not crash upon calling this new API?

In the previous versions we had to do a check before calling a new API.

Answer (score 0):

This is just speculation, but sometimes a "new" API was already available in the older versions of the OS, but has not been made available for developers outside of Apple. However, if you submit such an application to Apple there is a good chance that it will be rejected.